# How to return a pointer char from v8 to javascript

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, v8, node.js-addon

I would like to return a char pointer from v8 to javascript, but it does not work. In js the length of result is not good. For example outlength is 43529bytes in v8, in js I have only 4 bytes. Is it correct in using return  String::New((char *)img);

Javascript:

```
var result = module.encode();
console.log(result.length);
```

V8

```
Handle<Value> encode(const Arguments& args) {

  FILE *pInputFile = fopen ( "images/file.rgb" , "rb" );
    if (!pInputFile ) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s\n", "vr.rgb");
    exit(1);
   }
   fseek (pInputFile , 0 , SEEK_END);
   long lSizeInput = ftell (pInputFile );
   rewind (pInputFile );
   char *img=(char*) malloc(lSizeInput*sizeof( char ));
   fread (img,1,lSizeInput,pInputFile);

   cout<<"length = "<< lSizeInput<<endl;
   return  String::New((char *)img);

}
```

Comment: Probably not related, but I'm not seeing where you terminate that `char *`. `malloc` doesn't zero-out memory it gives you these days, does it? You probably want `img[lSizeInput] = 0;` after the `fread`, or give `String::New` `lSizeInput` as a second argument. (Though the `long` gives me pause in both cases...). (It's been 20+ years since I did any C or C++, so...)

Comment: Actually, `img[lSizeInput]` will address the first byte beyond the array. Remembering of course, that if an array has `n` elements, the last valid index will be `n-1`. :)

Comment: You probably want to return a buffer instead...